# Odoo 11 Qweb headers missing in PDF reports

Tags: odoo, odoo-11, qweb

Using Odoo 11 with wkhtmltopdf verion 0.12.1.3

All the default headers are not on any of the PDF reports I print, even when I try to preview the document templates in general settings.
I still have the footers though.

Furthermore the reports are very plain now, like the table-striped that has become a white plain column, or "row" that doesn't show the elements inside in a row but rather one under the other.

Edit :
To illustrate my problem here is what happen when I chose the Standard template in General Settings and I try to Preview the document.

[There is what happends](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PDGJi.png)

What's strange is that I didn't touch - I don't think so - this header in any way (even though I've done some custom reports but unrelated).

Here is the code of web.external_layout_standard:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<t t-name="web.external_layout_standard">
        <div class="header">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-3 mb4">
                    <img t-if="company.logo" t-att-src="'data:image/png;base64,%s' % to_text(company.logo)" style="max-height: 45px;"/>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-9 text-right" style="margin-top:22px;" t-field="company.report_header" name="moto"/>
            </div>
            <div t-if="company.logo or company.report_header" class="row zero_min_height">
                <div class="col-xs-12">
                    <div style="border-bottom: 1px solid black;"/>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-6" name="company_address">
                    <span t-field="company.partner_id" t-field-options="{&quot;widget&quot;: &quot;contact&quot;, &quot;fields&quot;: [&quot;address&quot;, &quot;name&quot;], &quot;no_marker&quot;: true}" style="border-bottom: 1px solid black; display:inline-block;"/>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="article o_report_layout_standard">
            <t t-raw="0"/>
        </div>

        <div class="footer">
            <div class="text-center" style="border-top: 1px solid black;">
                <ul class="list-inline mb4">
                    <li t-if="company.phone">Phone: <span t-field="company.phone"/></li>
                    <li t-if="company.email">Email: <span t-field="company.email"/></li>
                    <li t-if="company.website">Web: <span t-field="company.website"/></li>
                    <li t-if="company.vat"><t t-esc="company.country_id.vat_label or 'TIN'"/>: <span t-field="company.vat"/></li>
                </ul>

                <div name="financial_infos">
                    <span t-field="company.report_footer"/>
                </div>

                <div class="text-muted">
                    Page: <span class="page"/> / <span class="topage"/>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </t>
```

**EDIT temporary SOLUTION**

It might have been a cache problem since we were several people working on the same admin account at the same time.
Thus I copied the database. Checked it worked well in my new database (eureka!). Erased the old one. And changed the name of the copy by the old name.

BUT! at some point it keeps despairing again. I'm doing qweb changes in custom reports so I don't touch the headers but maybe it's connected...

Comment: Can you be more specific what exactly you want in apart from header issue ? Also from header issue you might get imported wrong template or something done with design issue. Can you show us the code and current report format you got?

Comment: I edited the post ! Thanks for the query.

Comment: Btw, how can I change to defalut parameters (design + templates) ?

Comment: How is you Odoo setup? Plain installation (apt or whatever) or a Docker Setup? Do you use a web proxy? Sometimes you have to add a system parameter in Odoo `report.url` with value `127.0.0.1:8069` (Maybe another port, depending on your setup).

Comment: Odoo was installed with official documentation available here : https://www.odoo.com/documentation/11.0/setup/install.html
And it was a source install (https://www.odoo.com/documentation/11.0/setup/install.html#source-install) on Ubuntu 18.
No proxy.
What is `report.url`? I don't know were to find it.

Comment: Solution at the end of the question !

Comment: I have the same problem, but it is only me working on.

Answer (score 2):

It seems that your pdf processor (wkthmltopdf) is not finding the proper CSS to form the reports. I solved this issue in Odoo 11 with the following steps:

1. Create a new system parameter `report.url`

For this go to `Settings -> Parameters -> System` and check if the parameter `report.url` exists. If not create it.

2. Set the value of `report.url` to http://127.0.0.1:8069 or http://0.0.0.0:8069

This is by the way the approach suggested by CZoellner. I have learnt more insight from the [discussion on headers and CSS in reports at Odoo Help](https://www.odoo.com/forum/help-1/question/how-to-change-the-value-of-web-base-url-to-get-the-correct-header-footer-css-82516).